# What can Hadoop do when I want to run concurrently the same Algorithm with 1000+ group of different parameters?

Tags: concurrency, hadoop

I want to run 1000+ different versions of the same algorithm(different arguments) at the same time, is Hadoop able to enhance the performance in this situation?
I have no knowledge of Hadoop currently, so the question might seem dumb.
I just want to know if Hadoop can do something about this, I don't need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No it can't. Simply because it does not care what kinds of Jobs are running at the same time. You will see a few performance improvements because the OS tries to cache your input. But generally the framework will not optimize this situation.

Hadoop wasn't built for these kinds of jobs and I very much doubt that you will get a good performance with Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about Hadoop the wrong way. The strength and advantage of using Hadoop lies in the fact that it allows distributed computing on "data-intensive" tasks. This means that it excels when you have a relatively small/simple amount of processing to do on a large amount of data (many terabytes to a few petabytes even).

So when you're considering Hadoop, the question is, "do I have a huge amount of data?" If yes, then it could work for you. It looks like you're answer is no, and you want to use it for concurrent processing. In this case, it's not the way to go for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with hadoop. You will only profit from the part of its functionality - distributed task scheduling, and will not profit from the rest.

Technically I would suggest the following way:
a) To make each set of parameters to be a single input split.
b) To make each mapper read the parameters from the input and read data from the HDFS directly (or from the distributed cache).

What you will get - distribution of our load over cluster, restart of the failed tasks.